# How to get the numbers of layer in a photo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, layers, photo-editing

In the book  page 139-140 ,
there are three separate photo layers: the text (Mungo National Park), a photo
of a rock carving, and a photo of sand and rock formations.

**How to get the numbers of layer in a photo?**

[image]

Comment: What file format is it?

Comment: You don't know... maybe the sky is from another picture, the tree, some other parts of the rocks.... There's no way to tell exactly how many layers it took to achieve this unless you have the original pictures. And even in this case, that won't tell you if there's extra layers for effects, light, etc.. So your guess is as good as anyone's guess and you seem to know already there's at least 3 different parts!

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to tell how many "layers" are in that photo.

it could be 2 layers, it could be 50 -- The blue sky... the clouds... the tree silhouette ... the butte... the large orange rock circle thing.. the cave painting... then 30 adjustment layers to tweak levels, curves, hue, saturation, vibrance...

There's *no way* to ever tell how many layers are used in any image other than viewing the original document.

Comment: From the looks of it, the sky and the orange circle thingy are definitely from other pictures.